# Attribute usemap in MJML

Tags: mjml

How can I use the usemap attribute in MJML? I have seen in the [documentation](https://documentation.mjml.io/#mj-image) that exists but isn't always supported. I searched for some reference from which to start but I couldn't find anything

I tried this but don't work and I don't have any idea about how to continue

```
<mjml>
  <mj-body>
    <mj-section>
      <mj-column>
        <mj-image usemap="#mappa" width="350px" src="https://www.online-image-editor.com//styles/2014/images/example_image.png" />
      </mj-column>
    </mj-section>
  </mj-body>
</mjml>
```